# Is there a way for the render job to check for resolution every time it goes to the next frame?

Tags: python, rendering, resolution

There is a similar question made two years ago but seems like the solution I am looking for wasn't found, so will ask again.

I need to render each frame with different resolution, and aspect ratio. 
If I render with a python script, all works great, loop sets resolution, executes render, and goes to the next frame.  This is not an optimal solution as I have tons of frames to render, and I would like to render it on the farm.

I tried to work with blender handlers they work on playback, if I press render, then the resolution is changing, but rendered images all have one resolution. it looks like when the render job is started it sets resolution and ignores changes given to resolution on each frame.

Is there a way for the render job to check for resolution every time it goes to the next frame?

```
import bpy
import sys
import json


sys.path.append('.')

resolution_path = bpy.path.abspath("//blender_input/data.json")

scene = bpy.context.scene
render = scene.render
output_path = render.filepath
output_nodes = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].node_tree

resolutions = []


def set_frame_range():
    scene.frame_start = 1
    scene.frame_end = len(resolutions)


def get_data_from_json():
    with open(resolution_path, "r") as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for res in data['resolutions']:
            resolutions.append(res)


get_data_from_json()
set_frame_range()


def set_output_resolutions(self):
    width = int(resolutions[scene.frame_current - 1][0])
    height = int(resolutions[scene.frame_current - 1][1])
    render.resolution_x = width
    render.resolution_y = height

    if width > height:
        render.pixel_aspect_x = 1
        render.pixel_aspect_y = width / height
    elif width <= height:
        render.pixel_aspect_x = height / width
        render.pixel_aspect_y = 1
    print(scene.frame_current)


bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(set_output_resolutions)
bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(set_output_resolutions)
```

if I run the following loop, then it works, but as mentioned above, this won't work on the renderfarm:

```
while frame_current <= scene.frame_end:
    width = int(resolutions[frame_current-1][0])
    height = int(resolutions[frame_current-1][1])

    scene.frame_set(frame_current)

    render.resolution_x = width
    render.resolution_y = height

    if width > height:
        render.pixel_aspect_x = 1
        render.pixel_aspect_y = width / height
    elif width <= height:
        render.pixel_aspect_x = height / width
        render.pixel_aspect_y = 1

    render.filepath = output_path + "." + str(frame_current)
    print("rendering frame: " + str(frame_current))

    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=False)

    frame_current = frame_current + 1
render.filepath = output_path
```

many thanks!!

Comment: In my opinion rendering at different sizes is not the most efficient workflow. Render once, to the largest size, and re-size, crop, or whatever it is you are doing, from that file. A script to do that in imagemagik or other script able app